# RoR migrations and data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I'm new to rails and I'm not sure I fully understand migrations. Is there a way to run them without losing table data? Also, is it bad to mess with old migrations to change table structures, or are you just supposed to create new ones?

Answer (score 0):

At version 0 there's nothing in the database. So how do you think you'll be able to keep data? :)

Usually it's not recommended to edit old migrations, because you'll have to reapply them. It's much easier to create new migration and roll it out.

Answer (score 0):

Migrations are nothing but a way to encapsulate the Database used, its just ruby code. Read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html
A migration which creates a table is supposed to drop the table when the same migration is reverted(:down). Since it deletes the table there is no chance of retaining data. 
Once a migration is executed for a table & you still need to alter structure, you should always create a new migration file for using the generator:
rails g migration AddColumnNameToTableName